# Button update new position

Tags: c#, button, position

I facing a simple question but make me confuse.

Some code as below :

Code 1

```
private void Main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X +10,label1.Location.Y + 10);

        }
    }
```

Code 2

```
private void Main_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {

            label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X +10,label1.Location.Y + 10);
            button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 1,button1.Location.Y);
        }
    }
```

Code 1 is working fine, but once after I add in a button in my form and the code to move the location, my "KEY.Left" don't return me anything (update position)... Could someone explain me about this??

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming that this is about Windows Forms:*

1. You can try to set your Form's `KeyPreview` property to `true` and handle the Form's `KeyUp` event

*or*

2. You can override `ProcessCmdKey` in your Form

   ```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
   {

       if (keyData == Keys.Left)
       {
           label1.Location = new Point(label1.Location.X + 10, label1.Location.Y + 10);
           button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X - 1, button1.Location.Y);
           return true;
       }
       return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
   }
   ```